# If statement ignoring operator?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to run an if statement inside of my for loop. However, it seems to be ignoring the operators...or something. I'm trying to get it to give the number of the question that contains the lowest total and the number that contains the highest total. Here are the methods:

**This one keeps returning 10:**

```
public int topRatedQuestion(){

    int answerTotal = 0;
    int highScore = 0;
    int topQuestion = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

         for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

              answerTotal = answerTotal + answerArray[i][j];      
          } //close for (j)

          if (answerTotal >= highScore){

               highScore = answerTotal;
               topQuestion = i + 1;
          }

    }//close for (i)
    return topQuestion;   
}
```

**This one returns 1 everytime:**.

```
public int lowRatedQuestion(){

    int answerTotal = 0;
    int lowScore = 1000;
    int lowQuestion = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

            answerTotal = answerTotal + answerArray[i][j];        
        }//close for (j)

        if (answerTotal <= lowScore){

            lowScore = answerTotal;
            lowQuestion = (i + 1);                
        }

    }//close for (i)

    return lowQuestion;

}
```

Comment: You need to reinitialize the `answersTotal` var in the `for (i)` in orden to count properly the next time. Something like: `answersTotal = 0; } //close for (i)`. Same problem with the `highScore`.

Comment: @AVolpe, I think it is `answerTotal` that needs to be reset at the beginning of each `i` loop

Comment: @asimes yes, my bad, I fixex my comment, thanks.

Comment: won't that reset the value of lowScore? I need it to retain its previous value so it can be compared to the new answerTotal. I was still typing this when you made your corrections. resetting answerTotal was the answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle thanks to @asimes I update my comment, you need to reinitialize the `answerTotal` to obtain a `new` as you say. If you don't do that, the `answerTotal` will be the same as the total of the previous answer.

Comment: @kyle what answerArray[i][j] contains? if you need to solve this can you participate please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring due to the fact that you are not refreshing the value of answertotal during the next iteration of the outer for loop. This is thus leading to the accumulation of the total from the previous row of the 2D-array.
    In order to correct the code initialize the answertotal variable between the for loops in this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int answertotal=0;

     for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
```